# Mongoose: update document & use middleware

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a case where I'm using mongoose `.pre('save')` hooks to denormalize some data to other documents. I'm struggling with a good solution to update data and keep denormalization consistent across the database. If I want to update a document, I consider three alternatives:

1. **Performing an atomic update**

The reason why I prefer not to do this is that it doesn't trigger my mongoose middleware that I need to denormalize my data.

2. **Using `.post('update')` hooks**

The problem with this method is for one that I can't tell in the hook which fields have been updated, right? So I should then assume all fields have been updated and denormalize data across the entire database? Seems very intense.

3. **Getting the document, modifying it, then saving it**

It seems convenient, but poses a risk to overwriting data, i.e. if the document was to be updated from elsewhere in the 'between'-moment.

*in* ***models/car.model.js:***

```
const { mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Manufacturer = require('./manufacturer.model.js');

const CarSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    manufacturer: {
        type: {
            _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            name: String,
        },
    },
});

CarSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    /*
    if (this.isModified('name')) {
        await Manufacturer.findByIdAndUpdate(this.manufacturer, {
            $set: {
                car-name: this.name,
            },
        });
    }
    */
    if (this.isModified('manufacturer') {
        const manufacturer = await Manufacturer.findOne({
            _id: this.manufacturer._id,
        }, {
            name: 1,
        });
        this.manufacturer.name = manufacturer.name;
    }
});
```

*in* ***controllers/car.controller.js:***

```
app.patch('/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
    const car = await Car.findById(req.params.id);
    // Bad solution, helps please
    for (var key in req.body) {
        car[key] = req.body[key];
    }
    await car.save();
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Any solution that could bring the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 2):

Number 2 is a viable option, you can just do [`this.getUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-getUpdate) using [`context: 'query'`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) in your `post('update')` hook. Also, what's wrong with performing an atomic update, like `updateOne()`?

Also, glad to see you're using async middleware, but just FYI you don't need [`next()` if you have an async hook function](http://thecodebarbarian.com/introducing-mongoose-5#promises-and-async-await-with-middleware).

Comment: Thanks Valeri! I added another example in my now updated question. Perhaps I want to use middleware to fetch the `Manufacturer` and store some of its data in my document. That would be why I refrain from using an atomic update.

Comment: But it could also be the case that I want to update any document that has reference to data of my `Car` document.

Comment: The approach in your new example of pulling data from the `Manufacturer` model if `manufacturer` changed is correct. However, you'll also need corresponding middleware on the `Manufacturer` model to update any `Car` docs that reference that `Manufacturer`.